# Do body composition analysers provide accurate readings or just estimates?

Tags: body-fat

Similar to the recent question [What is the error on various body fat percentages?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/30772/7951) I am looking for a gold-standard measure of Total Body Fat as a **possible** better predictor of Cardiovascular Disease Mortality in comparison to BMI ([Ortega, et al. 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4821662)) - see also [Considering obesity using BMI](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/11331).

Are body composition analysers such as [these from Tanita](https://tanita.eu/products/professional-body-composition-monitors) actually able to accurately measure Total Body Fat, Body Fat Percentage, Fat Free Mass, viceral fat levels etc. or are the readings they provide estimates?

How else can accurate measurements of total body fat be achieved?

### References

Ortega, F. B., Sui, X., Lavie, C. J., & Blair, S. N. (2016). Body mass index, the most widely used but also widely criticized index: would a criterion standard measure of total body fat be a better predictor of cardiovascular disease mortality?. In *Mayo Clinic Proceedings* (Vol. 91, No. 4, pp. 443-455). Elsevier. doi: [10.1016/j.mayocp.2016.01.008](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mayocp.2016.01.008) pmcid: [PMC4821662](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4821662)

Comment: You can be skinny and have fatty arteries.